# Xamarin.Forms seperation of design in Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am a little new to Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to find a way to separate the design of each devices like Android uses Material Design and I want Android to use that and IOS use something different.

I am trying to do that with Xamarin.Forms and what I know until now is that using Xaml to design the layout/storyboard, doesn't seem for me to separate it on the design for specific platform (i.e. Android by using support design or support widget libraries on the xaml).

Does anyone know how to say that if it is Android, use Material design or if it is IOS use another design (Maybe the OnPlatform tag would solve the issue. But it will maybe be too much?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the Material design in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<application 
  android:icon="@drawable/appicon" 
  android:label="Your app" 
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Material.Light">
</application>
```

This will only apply the design on Android devices since Material design and `AndroidManifest.xml` are not available on iOS.

Comment: cool. What I want to know too. Is that if there is a possible way to use these NuGet support libraries for Android to modify the design? For me it doesn't seem that it is possible when coding Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on Xamarin Blog.
https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/

Posted yesterday :P Thanks for answers! It helped a lot. Now I just miss on how to do it on IOS. but I guess it will maybe be simpler now.